# IF condition " Error: Syntax error. Missing '}' "

Tags: visualforce

Hi please check this coding and let me know what mistake I did

```
{!IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'TimeShare',
'Nights',IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'VTS',
'Nights',IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Points','Points',
IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Units','Units','false')))))}
```

Comment: Try formatting it properly, you can optimize this formula with CASE method

Comment: Sorry, I can't get you

Comment: Will you please explain in detail

Comment: One too many ) at the end

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the issue was identified in the comments, but I really do feel that you should have been able to work this one out yourself.

Trying to keep track of open/close parentheses, braces, or brackets becomes a lot harder after about 3 or so (ever try programming in Lisp?).

One of the easiest methods of keeping track of these things is to use *multiple lines, and indentation*. This keeps the number of parentheses/braces/brackets on any given line low enough for our monkey brains to manage, and makes finding mistakes a lot easier.

Keeping things on a single line:

```
{!IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'TimeShare', 'Nights',IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'VTS', 'Nights',IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Points','Points', IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Units','Units','false')))))}
```

Hard to see what (if anything) might be wrong...

Breaking things into multiple lines (at logical places):

```
{!
    IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'TimeShare',
        'Nights',
        IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'VTS',
            'Nights',
            IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Points',
                'Points',
                IF(Customer__c.Product_Category__c == 'Units',
                    'Units',
                    'false'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
}
```

In the second example, it's easy to see that you included an extra `)`.

You might not be able to use this multi-line approach in a visualforce page, but it's still a good approach to take for debugging.

There is also an argument for using the `CASE` function here, since you're checking a single field against multiple values. That would remove a lot of the bulk (and parentheses) from your merge expression. (It's a lot harder to mess up your parentheses if there's only one pair)

```
CASE(Customer__c.Product_Category__c,
    'TimeShare', 'Nights',
    'VTS', 'Nights',
    'Points', 'Points',
    'Units', 'Units',
    'false'
)
```